# How to set the wsdl generated webservice name?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I created a webservice with defined name:

```
@WebService(name = "MyService")
```

When I deploy that service, the wsdl is available at this service name:

```
Endpoint address: http://localhost:8080/myproject/services/MyService?wsdl
```

BUT the wsdl content definition show a `Service` keyword appended at my webservice that is already named `*Service`.

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MyServiceService">
```

How can I prevent the "Service" keyword being appended here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF will generate the value as name + "Service".  To override this value, you can set the serviceName attribute on the `@WebService` annotation, e.g.

`@WebService(name = "MyService", serviceName = "MyService")`